# apache rewrite syntax

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, googlebot

Trying to block Google bot and others from accessing some of my sites. Thing is I have one box that has a ton of virtual host files that do nothing more than do a proxy pass to other servers. I would like to block googlebot and would like avoid having to go to each individual `.htaccess` file.
I believe you can do this in apache2.conf (httpd.conf) but I believe there might be some differences in the syntax.
For example I know that this works if I stick it in my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [F,L] 

</IfModule>
```

but it doesn't seem to work in apache2. What would the exact syntax be?

`robots.txt` and `.htaccess` is not an option. Yes I know this setup sounds retarded because it is. I just inherited it.

Comment: That exact setup works perfectly for me in apache2. What does your rewrite log say?

Comment: my guess is mod_rewrite isn't enabled

Answer (score 0):

Rewriterules defined in a server-wide context are not automatically inherited in a virtual server context.
You will need to add this to each virtual host:

```
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions